Improving Robustness of LSTM Model for Stock Price Prediction
I am currently working on a Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) model for predicting stock prices. My model takes into account the fact that there are non-trading minutes with no data. I have also incorporated sentiment analysis into my model.
However, I am looking for ways to make my model more robust. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import os
import sys
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import requests
import tqdm

# Ensure necessary packages are installed
required_packages = [
    'pandas', 'numpy', 'matplotlib', 'scikit-learn', 
    'keras', 'tqdm', 'vaderSentiment', 'requests'
]

for package in required_packages:
    try:
        __import__(package)
    except ImportError:
        os.system(f'{sys.executable} -m pip install {package}')

# Define a custom callback for the progress bar
class TrainingProgressBar(Callback):
    def __init__(self, epochs):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=epochs, desc='Training Progress', unit='epoch')
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.progress_bar.update(1)
        self.progress_bar.set_postfix(loss=logs.get('loss', 0.0))
    
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        self.progress_bar.close()

# Function to handle the date parsing
def parse_dates(date_str):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(date_str, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', utc=True)
    except ValueError:
        return pd.to_datetime(date_str, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', utc=True)

# Load the data
data_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\combined_data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)

# Preprocess the data
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(parse_dates)
data = data.set_index('date')

# Check for and remove duplicate timestamps
data = data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

# Filter for trading hours and drop non-trading days
data = data.between_time('9:30', '16:00')
data = data[data.index.dayofweek < 5]  # Keep only weekdays (Monday to Friday)

# Reset the index to ensure continuity in the x-axis
data = data.reset_index()

# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data[['close']])

# Function to create datasets
def create_dataset(data, time_step=1):
    X, Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data) - time_step):
        a = data[i:(i + time_step)]
        X.append(a)
        Y.append(data[i + time_step, 0])
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)

time_step = 60  # Use the past 60 minutes for prediction

# K-Fold Cross-Validation
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
best_model = None
best_mae = float('inf')

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(scaled_data):
    # Scale data within the fold
    train_data, test_data = scaled_data[train_index], scaled_data[test_index]
    
    X_train, y_train = create_dataset(train_data, time_step)
    X_test, y_test = create_dataset(test_data, time_step)
    
    # Reshape the data
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1)
    
    # Build the LSTM model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(time_step, 1)))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(25))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    
    # Train the model
    epochs = 20
    batch_size = 32
    progress_bar = TrainingProgressBar(epochs)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, callbacks=[progress_bar])
    
    # Evaluate the model
    test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
    test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict)
    y_test_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test_inv, test_predict)
    
    if mae < best_mae:
        best_mae = mae
        best_model = model

print(f'Best Model MAE: {best_mae:.4f}')

# Fetch news data and perform sentiment analysis
def fetch_news_sentiment(api_key, query, from_date, to_date):
    url = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q={query}&from={from_date}&to={to_date}&sortBy=popularity&apiKey={api_key}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    articles = response.json().get('articles', [])
    
    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    sentiments = []
    
    for article in articles:
        title = article['title']
        description = article['description']
        if title:
            sentiments.append(analyzer.polarity_scores(title)['compound'])
        if description:
            sentiments.append(analyzer.polarity_scores(description)['compound'])
    
    if sentiments:
        return np.mean(sentiments)
    else:
        return 0

api_key = 'c6c6ebf7b64a48eba84c128370042247'
query = 'NVIDIA'
from_date = '2024-05-01'
to_date = '2024-05-30'
news_sentiment = fetch_news_sentiment(api_key, query, from_date, to_date)

# Add the sentiment score to the scaled data
# Assuming sentiment score varies over time, a more realistic approach would involve time-aligned sentiment scores
sentiment_column = np.full((scaled_data.shape[0], 1), news_sentiment)
enhanced_data = np.hstack((scaled_data, sentiment_column))

# Prepare training and test data with sentiment
train_size = int(len(enhanced_data) * 0.8)
train_data = enhanced_data[:train_size]
test_data = enhanced_data[train_size:]

X_train, y_train = create_dataset(train_data, time_step)
X_test, y_test = create_dataset(test_data, time_step)

# Debug prints for reshaping
print("X_train shape before reshaping:", X_train.shape)
print("X_test shape before reshaping:", X_test.shape)

# Reshape the data with two features (price and sentiment)
try:
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 2)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 2)
except ValueError as e:
    print("Error during reshaping:", e)
    print("Original X_train shape:", X_train.shape)
    print("Original X_test shape:", X_test.shape)
    print("Expected shape:", (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 2))
    sys.exit()

# Build the enhanced LSTM model
enhanced_model = Sequential()
enhanced_model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(time_step, 2)))
enhanced_model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
enhanced_model.add(Dense(25))
enhanced_model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
enhanced_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
epochs = 20
batch_size = 32
progress_bar = TrainingProgressBar(epochs)
enhanced_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, callbacks=[progress_bar])

# Predict and inverse transform the values
train_predict = enhanced_model.predict(X_train)
test_predict = enhanced_model.predict(X_test)
train_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predict[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1))
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1))

# Calculate metrics
y_test_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test_inv, test_predict)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test_inv, test_predict)
variance = np.var(test_predict - y_test_inv)

print(f'MAE: {mae:.4f}, MSE: {mse:.4f}, Variance: {variance:.4f}')

# Convert 'date' column back to datetime if reset_index was used
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

# Identify the indices corresponding to the start of each trading day
trading_day_starts = data[data['date'].dt.time == pd.Timestamp('09:30').time()].index
trading_day_labels = data.loc[trading_day_starts, 'date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(range(len(train_predict)), train_predict, color='blue', label='Train Prediction')
plt.plot(range(len(train_predict), len(train_predict) + len(test_predict)), test_predict, color='red', label='Test Prediction')
plt.plot(range(len(scaled_data)), scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_data), color='green', label='Original Data')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction with Sentiment Analysis')
plt.legend()

# Set x-ticks for better readability
plt.xticks(trading_day_starts, trading_day_labels, rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Plot only predictions
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(range(len(train_predict), len(train_predict) + len(test_predict)), test_predict, color='red', label='Test Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction (Only Predictions)')
plt.xticks(trading_day_starts, trading_day_labels, rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Forecast the next 2 trading days (approx. 780 minutes)
future_steps = 780  # 6.5 trading hours per day * 60 minutes
last_data = enhanced_data[-time_step:]
future_input = last_data.reshape((1, time_step, 2))
future_predictions = []

for _ in range(future_steps):
    prediction = enhanced_model.predict(future_input)
    future_predictions.append(prediction[0][0])
    future_input = np.append(future_input[:, 1:, :], [[[prediction[0][0], news_sentiment]]], axis=1)

# Inverse transform and plot future predictions
future_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(np.array(future_predictions).reshape(-1, 1))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(range(future_steps), future_predictions, color='blue', label='Future Predictions')
plt.xlabel('Minutes')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.title('Future Stock Price Prediction (Next 2 Trading Days)')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
````


Welcome to Cross Validated! “Robust” to what? Do you just want better performance in predicting returns?

Yes, because the current model seemingly just a moving average (Almost like shifting 2 minutes lag data to the right), and I think it is weird and useless

Predicting financial returns or prices is notorious for being brutally difficult. Do you have much expectation that your predictive model can do better than a simple benchmark? The "hopeless" in this link might take it a bit too far, but it is worth considering why you think you can do better than you are doing.
